# ¿Cómo puedo elevar una matriz a la N potencia?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrices, numpy

Estoy tratando de elevar una matriz a la N potencia con la librería numpy para generar una matriz aleatoria, el error que me tira es que cuando hago los cálculos matemáticos el resultado, no es el esperado, trato de hacerlo con los ciclos For para entender mejor la interacción de las matrices.

```
import numpy as np
fil1=2
col1=2
fil2=fil1
col2=col1
mat1 = random.random((fil1,col1))
mat2 = mat1
mat3 = np.zeros((fil1,col1))
temp = np.zeros((fil1,col1))
itera = 2
print('Matriz A:\n',mat1)
print('Matriz AxA:\n',mat2)
for i in range (0,itera):
    for r in range(0,fil1):
        for c in range (0,col1): 
            for k in range (0,fil2):
                mat3[r,c]+=mat1[r,k] * mat2[k,c]
                temp[r,c]=mat3[r,c]
                mat1[r,k] = mat3[r,c]
print('Potencia:\n',mat3)
print('Matriz:\n', temp)
```

El error se marca en `temp[r,c] = mat3[r,c]`

Un ejemplo claro sería lo siguiente:

```
A = [1 1  
     0 1]

A^2 = [1 1  * [1 1   =  [1 2
       0 1]   0 1]       0 1]

#En caso de que A^3 
A^3 = [1 2  * [1 1   =  [1 3
       0 1]    0 1]      0 1]

#En caso de que A^4 
A^4 = [1 3  * [1 1   =  [1 4
       0 1]    0 1]      0 1]
```

Comment: te sugiero consultar [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/199261/100828). Espero que sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 1):

El siguiente código puede ser útil:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,1],[0,1]])

def matMul(a,b):
    m_a = a.shape[0]
    n_a = a.shape[1]
    n_b = b.shape[1]
    c_ = np.array([[0,0],[0,0]])
    for i in range(m_a):
        for j in range(n_b):
            for k in range(n_a):
                c_[i,j] += a[i,k]*b[k,j]
    return c_


def matExp(a,n):
    n -= 1
    c_ = a.copy()
    for i in range(n):
        c_ = matMul(c_,a)
    return c_
```

Al llamar la función `matExp` puedes obtener el resultado de elevar una matriz a una potencia.

```
matExp(a,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

No necesitas implementar ningún bucle si dices que estás usando `numpy`. Tienes la función `numpy.linalg.matrix_power()`. Por ejemplo:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([ [1,1],
               [0,1] ])
result = np.linalg.matrix_power(a, 4)
print(result)
```

Resultado:

```
[[1 4]
 [0 1]]
```

También, para una sintaxis más cómoda, puedes crear `a` como una matriz (matrix) en lugar de un array. En ese caso puedes usar el operador `**` para elevarlo a una potencia:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.matrix([ [1,1],
               [0,1] ])
result = a**4
print(result)
```

```
[[1 4]
 [0 1]]
```

---

### Actualización

Si pese a disponer de numpy (que puede resolverte el problema con menos código y más eficiente, por estar implementado en C por debajo), quieres hacer la multiplicación "a mano" (es decir, implementando en python los bucles necesarios), entonces tu código estaba casi bien, pero tenía algún error de lógica.

Voy a ceñirme a tu código, usando tus mismos nombres de variables (aunque la elección de nombres no es la mejor), para que te sea más fácil ver dónde lo hacías mal. En todo caso, una implementación más limpia es la que te ha dado Daniel Urencio en otra respuesta.

La variable `mat1` contiene la matriz que quieres elevar a una potencia. La variable `mat2` es una copia de la misma matriz. Entiendo que es la matriz por la que vas a multiplicar `mat1`, y que por tanto en la primera iteración del bucle es igual a `mat1` para que el resultado sea `mat1` al cuadrado, pero en las siguientes iteraciones `mat2` debería contener el resultado de la multiplicación anterior, para que así se vaya "acumulando" una multiplicación sobre otra, llegando a la potencia deseada.

Tus fallos serían:

- Necesitas una tercera matriz auxiliar que contenga el resultado de la multiplicación mientras la estás calculando. Entiendo que ese es el papel de `mat3` en tu código. Esta variable por tanto debería ser inicializada con ceros antes de comenzar la multiplicación (es decir, antes del `for r`). Este es tu primer fallo.
- Por otro lado, una vez se ha terminado de computar la multiplicación (es decir, al salir del bucle `for r`, el resultado que tenemos en `mat3` debe ser copiado a `mat2` (este es tu segundo fallo, que haces esa copia dentro del bucle más interno, y sobre la matriz `mat1` en lugar de `mat2`).
- No veo para qué sirve la matriz adicional `temp`, que podemos eliminar (tercer fallo, aunque no afecta al funcionamiento).
- Finalmente, la variable `itera` es el número de iteraciones que se hará en el bucle exterior. Si itera=2 por ejemplo, el bucle se hará dos veces. En la primera iteración se calcula AxA, y en la segunda (AxA)xA, por lo que al final la potencia sería 3. Lo veo un poco confuso, pues es más fácil de entender si en lugar del número de iteraciones, especificas la potencia a la que lo quieres elevar. No es un fallo, pero mejora la legibilidad.

Al salir de todos los bucles, el resultado estará en `mat3` o `mat2` que valen lo mismo. Este sería el código con las correcciones antes indicadas:

```
import numpy as np
fil1=2
col1=2
fil2=fil1
col2=col1
mat1 = np.array([ [1,1], [0,1] ])
mat2 = mat1
print('Matriz A:\n',mat1)

potencia = 3
for i in range (0, potencia-1):
    mat3 = np.zeros((fil1,col1))
    for r in range(0,fil1):
        for c in range (0,col1): 
            for k in range (0,fil2):
                mat3[r,c]+=mat1[r,k] * mat2[k,c]
    mat2=mat3
print('Potencia:', potencia, '\n', mat3)
```

```
Matriz A:
 [[1 1]
 [0 1]]
Potencia: 3 
 [[1. 3.]
 [0. 1.]]
```

Comment: Solo aplico numpy para generar una matriz random, pero en caso de realizar con el ciclo For, como podría implementarlo ?

Comment: @Pedro Respuesta actualizada.  Mira si te sirve.